# how check if GetElementsByTagName not match

Tags: c#, xml

i have a script to load/read the xml to 15 texboxes with InnerText

here is the code.

```
doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(dlgOpenFile.FileName);
root = doc.DocumentElement;
txt1.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Seksi")[0].InnerText;
txt2.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Kota")[0].InnerText;
txt3.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Tanggal")[0].InnerText;
txt4.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("NoIntelejen")[0].InnerText;
txt5.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Peta")[0].InnerText;
txt6.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Kedar")[0].InnerText;
txt7.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Tahun")[0].InnerText;
txt8.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Lembar")[0].InnerText;
txt9.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("TugasPokok")[0].InnerText;
txt10.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Intelejen")[0].InnerText;
txt11.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Taktis")[0].InnerText;
txt12.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Personil")[0].InnerText;
txt13.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Logistik")[0].InnerText;
txt14.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Teritorial")[0].InnerText;
txt15.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Perhubungan")[0].InnerText;
```

when i load a correct xml, the xml success load to text box, but when the `GetElementsByTagName` is not match, show error **"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."**

in row

```
txt10.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Intelejen")[0].InnerText;
```

how to check if `GetElementsByTagName` not match , so when the elements not match, the app show message and cancel load?

Comment: You appear to be always using the `First` value of the collection from `GetElementsByTagName`...why not just use `SelectSingleNode`?

Answer (score 3):

The `GetElementsByTagName` method will return a node collection of all matches elements, if no matches are found then it will return an empty collection. You can test if the collection is empty by using the `Count` property. This is what you need:

```
var matches = root.GetElementsByTagName("Seksi");
if(matches.Count > 0)
    txt1.Text = matches[0].InnerText;
```

---

As you are doing this quite a few times it would be useful to create a helper function. Something like so:

```
public void SetTextForTag(XmlElement root, TextBox tb, string tag)
{
    var matches = root.GetElementsByTagName(tag);
    if(matches.Count > 0)
        tb.Text = matches[0].InnerText;
}
```

which you can use like this, for example:

```
SetTextForTag(root, txt1, "Seksi");
SetTextForTag(root, txt2, "Kota");
//and so on...
```

Comment: i have tried your code, no error when not element not matches, but i want, when the user load the not matches elements , the app show message box and cancel the load. @musefan

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a ternary operator like:

```
   txt1.Text = root.GetElementsByTagName("Seksi").Count < 1 ? "" : root.GetElementsByTagName("Seksi")[0].InnerText;
```

Comment: It is not efficient to call `GetElementsByTagName` twice

Comment: It doesn't matter how many lines of code it is, that means nothing to a compiled program. Calling that function twice means it has to run twice, and that could be an expensive function on large documents

Comment: Double the size program does not mean anything in run time?

Comment: Double the size is NOT determined by having twice as many lines. C# is a compiled programming language, your original code (as written) means nothing at run time

Answer (score 0):

You could DRY up your code some by use of this extension method

```
public static bool TryGetInnerText(this XmlElement root, string childName, out string text)
    {
         var children = root.GetElementsByTagName(childName);
         if(children.Count > 0){
               text = children[0].InnerText;
               return true;
         }
         text = null;
         return false;
    }
```

then you can call it like this:

```
 if(!root.TryGetInnerText("Seksi", out txt1.Text)){
      //notify the uesr that the Seksi wasn't found
 }
```

and that will handle the checks for you as well

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var element = root.GetElementsByTagName("Intelejen")[0];
if (element != null)
    txt10.Text = element.InnerText
```

Explanation: `root.GetElementsByTagName("Intelejen")[0]` returns null if no element is found. That is why `InnerText` throws a null exception

Comment: Why is my answer downvoted? Using the indexing operator on an empty XmlElementList does indeed return null and unlike other Lists doesn't throw an IndexOutOfRange exception.

Comment: not sure why it was downvoted, I guess maybe the downvoter didn't understand what you have since explained. I am reluctant to upvote just to counter the downvote though, sorry

Comment: Thanks for your replay because I was thinking that my code snippet was wrong.

Answer (score -2):

keep null checks in mind for non-existent elements, you can't assign what isn't there:

```
txt1.Text = (root.GetElementsByTagName("Seksi")[0] != null) 
   ? root.GetElementsByTagName("Seksi")[0].InnerText 
   : String.Empty;
```

Comment: This will cause the same error, because it is not `InnerText` that is null. It is the non-existent `[0]` element that is null

Comment: Still not ideal using `GetElementsByTagName` twice, but it should work so will remove downvote

Answer (score -2):

```
var elements = root.Elements("Seksi");
        if (elements.Any())
        {
            string txt = elements.First().Value;
        }
```

Comment: Function `Elements` does not exist for `XmlElement`, so this wont even compile

Comment: @musefan: do you have any restriction in using XDocument?

Comment: It isn't my question so I cannot dictate the requirements, but you did not even mention XDocument in your answer so how would the OP know it is a requirement of your solution to include it?

Comment: ok, you may be on v3.0. you can use extention methods: public static string GetFirstElementByTagName(this XmlElement element, string tagName)
        {
            XmlNodeList tagNodes = element.GetElementsByTagName(tagName);
            if (tagNodes.Count > 0)
            {
                return tagNodes[0].InnerText;
            }

            return string.Empty;
            //OR throw new DataException(string.Format("Element {0} not present. Cancelling.", tagName));
        }

Comment: I don't think you understand anything I am saying do you :(